# Failure to build when simulating iOS react-native app

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am attempting to perform `react-native ios` on an old project and it just can't seem to successfully build...

I'm not entirely sure which of the various console outputs is causing the issue.

The final output is

> ** BUILD FAILED **
> The following build commands failed:
> CompileC /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/some-id/Build-id/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseMessaging.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GtalkExtensions.pbobjc.o /Users/username/git/project-name/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging/Sources/Protos/GtalkExtensions.pbobjc.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')
> (1 failure)

I am running a M2 Macbook Pro whereas I believe this was developed older hardware, possibly mid-2016 Mac.

```
node -v: 16.10.0
yarn -v: 1.22.19
ruby -v: 2.7.6
xcode version: 14.1
```

I followed the instructions on the [official docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) on setting up the environment. I have run `yarn install` on the main root, `cd`'d into the `ios` directory and run `pod install` followed by `npx react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 14'`

After running the `pod install` however I do see the following, talking about Firebase version inconsistencies...

```
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `workspace-name`: Expo, RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNFBAnalytics, RNFBApp, RNFBDynamicLinks, RNFBIid, RNFBMessaging, RNGestureHandler, RNRate, RNScreens, RNVectorIcons, react-native-app-auth, react-native-geolocation, react-native-safe-area-context, and react-native-webview
Using Expo modules
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 67 dependencies from the Podfile and 83 total pods installed.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/analytics' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v10.0.0 but found v8.4.7, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v9.0.0 but found v8.4.7, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/iid' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v8.4.1 but found v8.4.7, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/messaging' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v8.4.1 but found v8.4.7, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] use_native_modules! skipped the react-native dependency 'react-native-apple-ads-attribution'. No podspec file was found.
    - Check to see if there is an updated version that contains the necessary podspec file
    - Contact the library maintainers or send them a PR to add a podspec. The react-native-webview podspec is a good example of a package.json driven podspec. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/react-native-webview.podspec
    - If necessary, you can disable autolinking for the dependency and link it manually. See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md#how-can-i-disable-autolinking-for-unsupported-library

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/analytics' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v10.0.0 but found v8.4.7, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v9.0.0 but found v8.4.7, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/iid' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v8.4.1 but found v8.4.7, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/messaging' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v8.4.1 but found v8.4.7, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] use_native_modules! skipped the react-native dependency 'react-native-apple-ads-attribution'. No podspec file was found.
    - Check to see if there is an updated version that contains the necessary podspec file
    - Contact the library maintainers or send them a PR to add a podspec. The react-native-webview podspec is a good example of a package.json driven podspec. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/react-native-webview.podspec
    - If necessary, you can disable autolinking for the dependency and link it manually. See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md#how-can-i-disable-autolinking-for-unsupported-library

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/analytics' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v10.0.0 but found v8.4.7, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v9.0.0 but found v8.4.7, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/iid' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v8.4.1 but found v8.4.7, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/messaging' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v8.4.1 but found v8.4.7, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.
```

There are earlier logs that state:

> /Users/username/git/project-name/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'React-RCTLinking' from project 'Pods')

However there are multiple logs like this, some stating `10.0`, some stating `9.0`...

There are some reports of manually linked dependencies, where I know they have been included via `yarn`...

> error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
> @react-native-community/geolocation (to unlink run: "react-native unlink @react-native-community/geolocation")
> appcenter (to unlink run: "react-native unlink appcenter")
> appcenter-crashes (to unlink run: "react-native unlink appcenter-crashes")
> react-native-screens (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-screens")
> react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")
> react-native-webview (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-webview")

The remaining logs:

> error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening workspace-name.xcworkspace.
> Command line invocation:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace worspace-name.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme workspace-name -destination id=xxx
>
> User defaults from command line:
> IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
>
> Prepare packages
>
> Computing target dependency graph and provisioning inputs
>
> Create build description
> Build description signature: 123
> Build description path: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/worspace-name-xxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/123-desc.xcbuild
>
> warning: Building targets in manual order is deprecated - choose Dependency Order in scheme settings instead, or set DISABLE_MANUAL_TARGET_ORDER_BUILD_WARNING in any of the targets in the current scheme to suppress this warning

Comment: were you able to figure out the solution?

Comment: @SahilKhurana not particularly. After further investigation it did appear that it was likely the firebase dependencies that were causing issues for whatever reason as uninstalling these and bypassing the code that used them let the app somewhat run locally but still with issues. Since the app is relatively old at this point and RN has moved on, we decided to spin up a new instance and migrate things over, updating everything as we go, as it was in desperate need of modernising.